# subset within a subset in R dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I need to remove several rows that meet a condition within a subset.

For instance, using the iris dataset, I would like to remove all the rows in which `Sepal.Width` = 3.2, but only within `setosa`

I have tried this:
`filter(iris, !Species %in% "setosa" & !Sepal.Width==3.2)`
But his removes all rows containing `setosa`and all rows in which `Sepal.Width==3.2`, rather than considering both conditions at the same time (i.e. only remove the rows of the condition within ‘setosa’ and leave the rest

Comment: General point: if you construct the correct condition, `filter` and analogues (`[]` and `subset`, for example) will all work and no subsetting of subsets is ever needed. In this case you could use `!(x & y)` as in SabDeM's answer, or the arguably less readable `!x | !y`

Comment: @Frank maybe I am wrong but I am thinking that I've learned such syntax  `!( <...conditions...> )` here on SO from you (or maybe another power user), because you commented my answer and made me realize the readability of it. As always thank you.

Comment: @fede_luppi I experienced the same thing with filter(), where it doesn't seem to properly honor boolean AND clauses for multiple criteria.  I don't know why this is, and I feel better about myself that someone else has the issue... Anyway the way I solved it was to invert the criteria so it was constructed out of NOT's and OR's rather than an AND.  Ugly and counterintuitive, but it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do so with `dplyr`:

```
iris %>% filter(!(Sepal.Width == 3.2 & Species == "setosa"))
```

or in base R:

```
iris[!(iris$Species == "setosa" & iris$Sepal.Width == 3.2), ]
```

and last but not least, with `subset`:

```
subset(iris, !(Species == "setosa" & Sepal.Width == 3.2))
```

But I think that there are other ways to do such subsetting operations, example, with data table.